# How do I warm up my biceps?

Tags: bodybuilding, body-fat, biceps

I have been going to gym for past 3 months.

How do I warm up my  biceps? Please give me some suggestion.
I dont know the rules.

What are the steps for improve my biceps?

Whether work out in low weight is improve our Musles?

Comment: Use them to lift something. I'd post an answer, but seriously?

Comment: i always use high weights to work out sample.. But it leads to pain in my hand..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In general, warming up your muscles only requires performing the movement with lower weights.  It's fine to use sets of 5 and then taper off the closer you get to your work weight.

However, if you are having pain in your hand, I would check your form.  Is that pain shooting up from the elbow?  If so, it's possible that you are putting too much strain on that joint and have developed a bit of tendinitis.

Make sure you are exercising the muscles you think you are.  For example, if you body is swaying just to get the bar up while doing barbell curls, you need to strengthen your core before you can improve your biceps--which in general is not a bad idea.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're being kind of vague here, I can only give you a vague answer. If your biceps are not improving, then you are not providing them enough of a stimulus to produce an adaptive response (growth) from them. I can do almost all the bicep training I need with chin-ups or weighted chin-ups.

What are your goals? Health? Longevity? Performance?

Comment: health is most important thing.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for ways to improve your bicep muscles, there are many excersises you can do.

A great way is jumping on to a bar (which you would use for pullups), getting your head above the bar, and then very slowly lowering yourself down. Repeating this 5 times will leave you very exhausted, but repetition over time will drastically improve your biceps.

If you are looking for a good way to train other muscles, a simple way to do this is the 15, 12, 10, 8, 6, 4 method. You start on an easy weight for yourself, and do 15 reps. Move he weight slightly lower, and do 12 of those. Keep lowering the weight until you get to 4. If you can do 4 of this weight, lower it even further and further until you can do no more.